# ¿Cómo unir filas repetidas? en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una problema con una consulta el cual quiero que las filas repetidas se unan en una sola, a continuación dare un ejemplo de lo que tengo y de lo que posiblemente quiero (si es posible realizarlo):

Lo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo anterior solamente es un ejemplo simplificado, la consulta real es esta:

```
SELECT fun.documento as documento_evaluador, fun.nombre as 
       Nombre_Evaluador, (select documento from funcionario where id= 
       resul.idFuncionario) as documento, (select nombre from funcionario 
       where id= resul.idFuncionario) as Nombre_Evaluado, FORMAT 
      (AVG(resul.valor),0) as valor, carcom.esperado as valor_esperado, 
      (SELECT IF(valor<valor_esperado, 'inferior', '')) AS inferior, 
      (SELECT IF(valor=valor_esperado, 'esperado', '')) AS esperado, 
      (SELECT IF(valor>valor_esperado, 'superior', '')) AS superior , 
      comp.nombre as nombre_competencia, obj.observaciones, obj.fortalezas, 
      obj.oportunidades, obj.formacion from resultados resul, competencia 
      comp, funcionario fun, nucleo nuc, cargoCompetencia carcom, objetivos 
      obj where resul.idEvaluador = fun.id and resul.nucleo = nuc.id and 
      nuc.idCompetencia = comp.id and carcom.idCargo = fun.cargo and 
      obj.idFuncionario = resul.IdFuncionario 
      GROUP BY Nombre_Evaluado, comp.id
```

Los campos que se repiten y que quiero que se unan o que se coloquen una sola fila son:

```
obj.observaciones, obj.fortalezas, obj.oportunidades, obj.formacion
```

He intentado muchas cosas pero aun así no me resultan.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: yo creo que eso no lo podrias hacer en la consulta peo lo podrias hacer en el procesado de los datos

Comment: Eso no se puede al menos no con SQL. SQL te regresa el resultado por tupla con cada uno de sus valores por columna, no se puede generalizar de esa manera. Como comenta Rene lo que podrias hacer seria transformar tu salida de la base de datos en la vista de tu proyecto para que se muestre asi, pero eso dependera ya de como estés trabajando tu proyecto

Comment: eso lo tienes que hacer desde tu interfaz de sistema o en un reporte si asi lo haces... mysql, sql no te generara eso

Answer (score -1):

el tema es que SQL se encarga de obtener datos ya que es un lenguage para comunicarse con la bd , no de como se muestran eso lo hace una interfaz visual.

lo que podrias hacer es hacer un order by de esos atributos que solicitas.

luego los podes obtener con un cliente tipo MySQLWorkbench(ponele hay una banda usa el que quieras) y los exportas a un csv.

luego abris el csv con excel(ponele tambien podes usar openoffice) y ahi como ya los tenes ordenados combinar las celdas es algo trivial